# Unexpected Identifier on node_modules package import

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mapbox, yarnpkg

I'm trying to use this [mapbox accessibility plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-accessibility) but once I install the plugin into my project, I get the following error on each import statement:

```
.../node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-accessibility/index.js:3

import xtend from 'xtend';
       ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

It seems to me that the packages' dependencies are not being read/installed

I've tried/considered:

- jumping into the package from within node_modules and running the
  yarn command (which shouldn't be necessary because I have a yarn.lock
  file which does that for me)
- changing the syntax to use require syntax in place of import
- that my project has no html file to load "type: module" in a script tag

Has anyone come across this and know how i can resolve it?

Comment: What build tool and version are you using? Does it support ESM modules?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you forgot to use babel to convert ES6 syntax.

> import is ES6 syntax

If you are using webpack, you need to install babel-loader.

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

and add config in your webpack.config.js

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Or you can try follow that require your package:

```
var xtend = require('xtend');
```